# Dynamic controls into object typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I got a form, which must be filled by a main person, and he can also fill the form for his spouse and children. 
[(Picture of the form)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRmnd.jpg)
It was working fine until the children requirement.

I made this model:

```
export class RequestForm{

 model = {
    main: { apellido: "", nombre: "", documento: "", sexo: "", fechaNacimiento: "", localidad: "", calle: 0, piso: 0, depto: 0, edificio: 0, telefono: "", celular: "", mail: "" },
    spouse: { apellido: "", nombre: "", documento: "", sexo: "", fechaNacimiento: "", localidad: "", calle: 0, piso: 0, depto: 0, edificio: 0, telefono: "", celular: "", mail: "" },
    children: [{ apellido: "", nombre: "", documento: "", sexo: "", fechaNacimiento: "", localidad: "", calle: 0, piso: 0, depto: 0, edificio: 0, telefono: "", celular: "", mail: "" }]
};
```

then, when Finish Form button is clicked, this function is called:

```
 finish() {
    this.model.main= {
        apellido: this.titularApellido.value, nombre: this.titularNombre.value, documento: this.titularDocumento.value
        , sexo: this.titularSexo.value, fechaNacimiento: this.titularFechaNacimiento.value, localidad: this.titularLocalidad.value
        , calle: this.titularCalle.value, piso: this.titularPiso.value, depto: this.titularDepto.value, edificio: this.titularEdificio.value
        , telefono: this.titularTelefono.value, celular: this.titularCelular.value, mail: this.titularMail.value
    };

    this.model.spouse = {
        apellido: this.conyugeApellido.value, nombre: this.conyugeNombre.value, documento: this.conyugeDocumento.value
        , sexo: this.conyugeSexo.value, fechaNacimiento: this.conyugeFechaNacimiento.value, localidad: this.titularLocalidad.value
        , calle: this.titularCalle.value, piso: this.titularPiso.value, depto: this.titularDepto.value, edificio: this.titularEdificio.value
        , telefono: this.conyugeTelefono.value, celular: this.conyugeCelular.value, mail: this.conyugeMail.value
    };       

    this.persistPerson(this.model.main);
    this.persistPerson(this.model.spouse);
}
```

I dont really know how to make the children controls dynamically and then be binded in the finish function. 
There is an input property ngModel but when I add it, the control breaks.

Thanks

PD. I made this to repeat the controls, but I cant set an id to the controls, so I lose the reference. When I did this, children was an array, and + and - button pushes and remove objects from the array

```
                        <ul style="list-style-type:decimal">
                            <li *ngFor="let child of children" style="display:list-item">

                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <md-input textoLabel="Apellido" type="text" [disabled]="esModoVisualizacion()"
                                                      placeholder="Apellido"
                                                      style="width:130px;"></md-input>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <md-input ..
                                              .
                                              .
                                </table>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
```

Comment: Your `finish` function looks like a nightmare to maintain :D I suggest you take a look at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html You can use the Object created by the form to process the form data, instead of using  the huge amount of variables you are now using. That's my suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comment, I would suggest you use dynamic form, which would let you have a nice object to work with and extract values:

So a simplified example based on your code, using `FormGroup`, `FormControl` and `FormArray`. You can also use validators to check that your form is valid.

So start off with a FormGroup, where you add all your formcontrol. First import necessary things and inject FormBuilder in your constructor:

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {  }
```

Then build form

```
patientForm: FormGroup;

ngOnInit() {
  this.patientForm = this.fb.group({
    firstname: ['', [Validators.required]], // add different validators
    lastname: ['']
    children: this.fb.array([ // create an FormArray for children
      this.initChildren()
    ])
  });
}
```

Then build you `FormArray` for children and method for adding new child in your form:

```
initChildren() {
  return this.fb.group({ // create a new group for children
    firstname: ['']
  })
}

addChild() { // adds a new formcontrol to your children formarray
  const control = <FormArray>this.patientForm.controls['children'];
  control.push(this.initChildren())
}
```

Then create your actual form in the view:

```
<form [formGroup]="patientForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(patientForm.value)"> <!-- add formgroup -->
  <label>Patient firstname: </label>
  <input formControlName="firstname"/> <!-- all fields need corresponding formcontrol name -->
  <label>Patient lastname: </label>
  <input formControlName="lastname"/>

  <div formArrayName="children"> <!-- Your formarray and below iterate the array -->
    <div *ngFor="let child of patientForm.controls.children.controls; let i = index" >
      <div formGroupName="{{i}}"> <!-- All children need unique formControl, here we used index -->
        <label>Child {{i+1}} firstname: </label>
        <input formControlName="firstname" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

This way you get a nice Object to work with and can get rid of all `[(ngModel)]` which makes your life so much easier ;)

With the above code upon submit you would end up with an Object like so:

```
{
  "firstname": "",
  "lastname": "",
  "children": [
    {
      "firstname": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

This [**link**](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-deal-with-different-form-controls-in-angular-2) could be helpful, this link basically shows the example I have created for you, but with further explanations, and I also created a [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/FF6X94J9QveqaHCU5Cpq?p=preview) for you with the above code! :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much! I had considerate that the model have a lot of behaviour and have to be consistent, so I made a class Person and put that objects into the model